# does UseCases need UseCasesImplements too in flutter clean architecture

Tags: flutter, dart

im in the middle of learning `flutter clean architecture`, overall im understand now but i have one question about UseCases i know what it's for but seeing `Entity` has `Model` and `Repository` has `RepositoryImplements` does `UseCases` need `UseCasesImplements` too ? since domain is only the blueprint

```
class TodoUseCases {
  final todoRepo = TodoRepositoryImpl();

  Future<Either<Failure, List<TodoEntity>>> getTodo() async {
    return todoRepo.getTodoFromDataSource();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code that I see you can create a Baseusecase class where you can add some generics and simplify the code.

```
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';

abstract class BaseUseCase<T, P> {
  Future<Either<Failure, T>> execute(P params);
}

class Failure {
  final String type;
  final String error;
  Failure(this.type, this.error);
}
// This is a simple failure class that might have type of failure and error.

class TodoUseCase extends BaseUseCase<List<String>, SampleUseCaseParams> {
  // Any RepoImplementation dependency passed via constructor
  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, List<String>>> execute(SampleUseCaseParams params) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
    // Make the repo call over here.
  }
}

class SampleUseCaseParams {
  final String parameterOne;

  SampleUseCaseParams(this.parameterOne);
}
```

Now from the code above you can extend the baseUseCase class for every usecase class and then there will be a method that you need to override.
But first as we are using the generics we have to pass 2 paramters for the base class

1. return type that is model that you are expecting.
2. UseCaseParams that are the paramters that you get from ui layer and want to send to the repository

There is no need of any implementation,But its up to you the above code is a simplification for developers ease.